# The Leibniz rule in Euler's works

Tags: integration, reference-request, definite-integrals, math-history

Does anyone know if the Leibniz rule (the method of differentiation under the integral sign), or a variation thereof, has ever appeared in any of Euler's papers? Any references would be appreciated. Moreover, does anyone know who was the first person to actually use the Leibniz rule? Was it Leibniz, or was the rule simply attributed to him?

Comment: Isn't the Leibniz rule usually said to mean what some colloquially call the 'product rule' but applied to a more general algebraic setting (when concerning derivations of an algebra)? I think 'differentiation under the integral sign' is more commonly called the Leibniz *integral* rule.

Comment: Your question about what Leibniz did for the rule about differentiating under the integral sign to be named after him is answered at https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/8132/.